# PostgreSql - Having trouble displaying my table using perform statment in my function

Tags: postgresql

This is the perform statement I use:

```
perform * from table1;
```

But when I execute the function the doesn't display the table onto the terminal. There are no errors produced, the table just doesn't show up.

My function:

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION addToTable (number INTEGER,NAME VARCHAR(15))
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1
    VALUES (
        number
        ,NAME
        );
    perform *
    FROM table1;
END;$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: @Vivek.S select wont work because it will give error saying that "query has no destination for result data". Thats why I use perform, but I dont know why there is no table showing when I execute the function.

Comment: @Vivek.S Im getting error after doing perform select saying "ERROR: syntax error at or near "select". The function is a void function.

Comment: As I already said you must show the entire function and refer http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT

Comment: @Vivek.S I have posted the entire function. It is very simple, I dont understand why it is not displaying table even thought it is not producing any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION addToTable_1 (num INTEGER,nam VARCHAR(15))
RETURNS setof table11 AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format( 'insert into table11 values(%s,%s) ',num,quote_literal(nam));
    RETURN QUERY
    EXECUTE 'select * from table11';
END;$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call it :  `select * from addToTable_1(2,'User')`

Comment: How does the reuturns know which table we are returning? We are only telling it name and number but we dont mention which table.

Comment: you want to get all the rows from `table1` or want only inserted rows ??,BTW `returning *` will returns all the inserted rows in `table1`

Comment: I want all the rows and all collumns of the table to be printed.

Comment: Thank you it works! Is it possible to add more than one reuturn table? Eg: RETURNS setof table1, table2, table3 AS $$

Comment: If all the column's datatype in each table and return column count are same then I have a workaround for that

Comment: Just did. Could you please answer my question in the previous comment. Is it possible to add more than one reuturn table? Eg: RETURNS setof table1, table2, table3 AS $$

Comment: `RETURNS setof table1, table2, table3` ain't possible

Comment: No they are diffrent tables with diffrent attributes :/

Comment: Ask a new question that's better IMO